# Copy every 2nd matrix element in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to copy every 2nd matrix element in Python.

For example:

```
arr1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
        [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

The desired array should be:

```
       [2, 4]
       [7, 9]
       [12, 14]
```

What's the easiest way to accomplish that?

Comment: That is not even valid Python code, nor valid output. Could you produce something a bit more precise? Also, what did you try?

Comment: You have to search a bit but the answer is usually out there one google search away.

Comment: is your `arr1` a `list` or a `numpy.array`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just slice the columns:

```
arr1_sliced = arr1[:,1::2]
# if arr1 is a python list, use 
arr1_sliced = np.array(arr1)[:,1::2]

print(arr1_sliced)

# [[ 2  4]
#  [ 7  9]
#  [12 14]]
```

Comment: What is that trick with comma in the slice? Have never seen that syntax

Comment: @go2nirvana It's not a trick, it's [numpy slicing syntax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html), don't expect to use this in pure python code. This answer makes the implicit assumption that `arr1` is already a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]

[a[1::2] for a in arr1]
```

You have a list of lists, not an array. Anyhow, i) list comprehension to look at each list in your list of lists. ii) the 2 in `1::2` gives a stride of 2, i.e., every second element. iii) the 1 in `1::2` means that we start at the second (i.e. 1 in 0-based index) element, which it appears you want

Answer (score 0):

`arr1` is just a syntax error from my point of view. if you meant

```
arr1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

A solution might be:

```
arr2 = [element[1::2] for element in arr1]
```

arr2 prints out:

```
>>> arr2
[[2, 4], [7, 9], [12, 14]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the NumPy function you can use a relevant filter like:

```
import numpy as np
filter_arr = []

# go through each element in arr
for element in arr:
  # if the element is completely divisble by 2, set the value to True, otherwise False
  if element % 2 == 0:
    filter_arr.append(True)
  else:
    filter_arr.append(False)
```

Then apply the filter on your data:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
newarr = arr[filter_arr] 
print(filter_arr)
print(newarr)
```

This example is taken from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_filter.asp).